# Windows Hyper-V Debian going into Read Only mode

Tags: debian, hyper-v-server-2012, read-only

I am running Debian 7.8 (wheezy) which is installed on a Windows Hyper-V server (not managed by me).  However, the server frequently goes into 'read only' mode and I am not sure why.  I have looked in dmesg but, to be honest, I do not know what I am looking at or for.  I ran fsck after reboot and there were errors e.g.

```
fsck died with exit status 4
...
Inotes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found. Fix
Inode <number> was part of the orphaned inode list. FIXED
...
Block bitmap differences: ....
Free blocks count wrong for group ...
```

After the reboot everything is ok.

Here is the output from dmesg after I ran fsck:

```
    [    5.951324] scsi scan: INQUIRY result too short (5), using 36
    [    5.951735] scsi scan: INQUIRY result too short (5), using 36
    [    5.951933] input: Microsoft Vmbus HID-compliant Mouse as /devices/virtual/input/input1
    [    5.952228] hid 0006:045E:0621.0001: input: <UNKNOWN> HID v0.01 Mouse [Microsoft Vmbus HID-compliant Mouse] on
    [    5.953338] hv_netvsc: hv_netvsc channel opened successfully
    [    6.057589] hv_netvsc vmbus_0_14: Device MAC 00:15:5d:00:fa:01 link state up
    [   10.954244] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 1006632960 512-byte logical blocks: (515 GB/480 GiB)
    [   10.954325] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
    [   10.954330] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 0f 00 00 00
    [   10.954539] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
    [   10.956129]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
    [   10.957221] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
    [   11.311017] PM: Starting manual resume from disk
    [   11.311022] PM: Hibernation image partition 8:5 present
    [   11.311024] PM: Looking for hibernation image.
    [   11.311494] PM: Image not found (code -22)
    [   11.311497] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
    [   11.404052] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    [   12.562030] udevd[348]: starting version 175
    [   12.959687] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
    [   12.959696] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
    [   12.977694] hv_utils: Registering HyperV Utility Driver
    [   12.977698] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_util
    [   13.080426] piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
    [   13.083881] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input3
    [   13.170434] alg: No test for __gcm-aes-aesni (__driver-gcm-aes-aesni)
    [   13.507475] trackpoint.c: failed to get extended button data
    [   16.708356] IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x01, buttons: 0/0
    [   16.710497] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
    [   19.075083] Adding 16773116k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16773116k
    [   19.099050] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
    [   19.335774] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
    [   19.412413] loop: module loaded
    [   20.685798] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
    [   20.685802] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
    [   20.685811] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
    [   20.685813] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
    [   20.721997] FS-Cache: Loaded
    [   20.754261] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
    [   20.763161] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
    [   23.477630] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
    [   23.477651] NET: Registered protocol family 31
    [   23.477653] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [   23.477656] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [   23.477658] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [   23.477849] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [   23.488920] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
    [   23.488926] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
    [   23.488928] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
    [   23.496819] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [   23.496822] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [   28.716625] postgres (3298): /proc/3298/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/3298/oom_score_adj instead.
    [   41.096759] mtrr: type mismatch for f8000000,400000 old: write-back new: write-combining
    [   56.353460] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_1: cmd 0x85 scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x86
    [   56.353465] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_1: stor pkt ffff8801fbb0e2c0 autosense data valid - len 18
    [   56.353468] storvsc: Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
    [   56.353472] storvsc: Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
```

Any pointers to log files that I could look in would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be occurring due to backups, please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1445195 for the related issue posted on the Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: Thank you,  looks like the same issue.  How would I go about applying the update baring in mind I am using debian and not ubuntu?